# Python is throwing error when website is not reachable

Tags: python

I have the following code to check if a specific website is available.

```
import urllib.request
with open("addresses.txt") as file:
url_list = file.read()
url_list = url_list.splitlines()

print("Chcking the repsonse code for the webiste")
for url in url_list:

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
response = (f"{response} available")
if "200 available" in response:
    print(f"{url} is up and running")
else:
    print(f"{url} is not reachable")
```

The code is working and okay until the website is reachable, but if a website is down it doesn't print out the message that "google.com is not reachable" but instead throws an error.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMt2M.png)

Sorry if the code is not so professional,I'm new to python so any help would be helpful here.

Comment: If you want to catch the exception, wrap the call inside a `try/except` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want do do something like this:

```
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
    response = (f"{response} available")
    if "200 available" in response:
        print(f"{url} is up and running")
    else:
        print(f"{url} is not reachable") 
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Attempting to contact {url} led to error:\n{ex}")
```